# Parsley: Validating optional field is equal to another

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

In using the [Parsley JS library](https://parsleyjs.org/), I am having trouble validating a field is equal to another when the fields are not required.

In this case, I need to confirm an updated password matches a confirmation field. When the fields are required (when the user is created) I have no problem. But when the password fields are not required (when updating the user), I cannot get Parsley to validate the field when the value is empty.

According to [the docs](https://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#usage-field), I should be able to use the `data-parsley-validate-if-empty` attribute, but this does not seem to be doing anything at all.

Here's what I have:

```
<div class="mb-3">

    <label for="password" class="form-label">New password (leave blank to
        remain unchanged)</label>

    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"
           class="form-control"
           minlength="6"
           data-parsley-minlength-message="Password must be at least 6 characters"/>

</div>

<div class="mb-3">

    <label for="passwordConfirm" class="form-label">Confirm new
        password</label>

    <input type="password" id="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm"
           class="form-control"
           minlength="6"
           data-parsley-validate-if-empty="true"
           data-parsley-equalto="#password"
           data-parsley-minlength-message="Password must be at least 6 characters"
           data-parsley-equalto-message="Value must match Password field"/>

</div>
```

Parsley is loading fine- the rest of the form is validated correctly. I just can't get Parsley to check that the `passwordConfirm` field matches the `password` field when the value of `passwordConfirm` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

`validate-if-empty` has unclear semantics for builtin validators. See [this issue](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/1151). In this example, what about the min-length?

Comment: `min-length` validates if something is entered in the field. Everything works as intended unless the field is empty, in which case it never validates against being equal to `#password`